# Imagemagick convert: use Pango to format captions in auto generated slides

Tags: parsing, imagemagick, png, pango, captions

I use this code to **auto generate slides from a .txt file** where I wrote captions this way:

```
CAPTION 1

CAPTION 2

...
```

CAPTION N

This is the script I use

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
# loop through files
while IFS= read -r p;  do
  # if it's not an empty line
  if ! [ -z "$p"]; then
    # echo line
    echo "$p";
    convert -background none -font Trebuchet-MS -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center -draw  "text 0,300 'pango:$p'" slide_template.png slides/slide-$i.png
    i=$((i+1))
  fi;
# pass input
done <$@
```

*slide_template.png* is simply an **empty** (transparent) **1920x1080 png**.

I pass my .txt file this way:

```
$ sh my_script.sh my_file.txt
```

And it generates my slides in */slides*.

Now I'd like to use some **format code** into my slides, like

```
MY <b>CAPTION</b> 1

MY <i>CAPTION</i> 2

...

MY CAPTION N
```

But **I can't understand how to use pango in my previous code**. I need to **reposition** my caption line **centered, 300 pixels from the bottom.**

If I use:

```
convert -background none -font Trebuchet-MS -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center -draw  "text 0,300 '$p'" slide_template.png slides/slide-$i.png
```

I get:

[image: correctly positioned but non parsed caption]

If I use this line:

```
convert -background none -font Trebuchet-MS -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center pango:"$p" slide_template.png slides/slide-$i.png
```

I get **TWO files** (why?), where the first one is **correctly parsed** but **cropped to the text size**:

[image: cropped caption]

And the second one is the background. Filenames this way are *slide-0-0.png* and *slide-0-1.png*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: I need to pipe one image to another.

The first contains the formatted code, the second overlays the piped data onto the background.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
# loop through files
while IFS= read -r p;  do
  # if it's not an empty line
  if ! [ -z "$p"]; then
    convert -background none -font Trebuchet-MS -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center -size 1920x300 pango:"$p" png:- | convert slide_template.png png:- -geometry +0+800 -composite  slides/slide-$i.png
    i=$((i+1))
  fi;
# pass input
done <$@
```